# SQL help needed - Migrating data from WordPress custom fields to CMB2 (custom meta boxes)

Tags: mysql, sql, wordpress

I'm trying to migrate data from a bunch of WordPress custom fields from about 50 posts to [CMB2](https://github.com/WebDevStudios/CMB2)
The data I'm looking for is in `wp_postmeta` table with `wpcf-contact-[field-name]` meta keys and the target meta key is `_program_contact_contact_group` which is an array and looks like this with demo content:

```
a:1{i:0;a:7{s:12:"contact_name";s:5:"cname";s:16:"contact_position";s:6:"ctitle";s:13:"contact_email";s:6:"cemail";s:15:"contact_address";s:8:"caddress";s:20:"contact_organization";s:13:"corganization";s:13:"contact_phone";s:6:"cphone";s:11:"contact_fax";s:4:"cfax";}}
```

Any help about how could this be done with SQL would be appreciated.
Thanks!

Comment: You should try something by yourself first and post that code if it doesn't work.